# Integral of $\sin (x^3)dx$

Tags: integration, derivatives

$$\int \sin (x^3)dx$$
I have tried some substitutions, but I haven't reached the goal... Can you help me?

Comment: As far as I recall, this one can't be written in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: In terms of the incomplete gamma function? http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%28x^3%29   Not $\int \sin^3(x) dx$?

Comment: @sunrise What exactly is the goal here?  Is the context really to compute the indefinite integral, or to compute a specific definite integral (as in Lucian's answer), or just to study convergence of the improper integral.  The latter two are much more typical questions than the original.

Answer (score 7):

By combining [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula) with the integral expression for the [$\Gamma$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), we have, for $n>1$ $$\int_0^\infty\sin(x^n)~dx~=~\bigg(\frac1n\bigg){\large!}~\sin\frac\pi{2n}$$ and $$\int_0^\infty\cos(x^n)~dx~=~\bigg(\frac1n\bigg){\large!}~\cos\frac\pi{2n}$$ Given the fact that your integral is indefinite, its expression is very similar, but it involves the [incomplete $\Gamma$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function), rather than the classical one.

Comment: See also [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) and the [Risch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm).

Answer (score 6):

Possibly this is not useful to you, but...

$$\sin(x^3)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^{6n+3}}{(2n+1)!}$$

so

$$\int\sin(x^3)dx=C+\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^{6n+4}}{(2n+1)!(6n+4)}$$

Answer (score 4):

Your integral is the imaginary part of the Fresnel integral:

$$ \int \exp{(\mathrm{i} x^3)} \, \mathrm{d}x = x \, {}_1F_1(1/3,4/3,\mathrm{i}x^3), $$ where I have substituted $n=3$ and $m = 0$ from [***here***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral#Generalization)·

Answer (score 2):

First note that

$$\int sin(x^3)dx = \frac{1}{2}\left(\int i e^{ix^3}dx - \int i e^{-ix^3}dx\right)$$

For the first integral

$$I_1 = \int ie^{ix^3}dx$$

change variables with $u=ix^3$, $x = -\sqrt[3]{iu}$ and

$$dx = -\frac{1}{3i} \frac{du}{\sqrt[3]{u^2}}$$

then

$$I_1 = -\frac{1}{3} \int u^{-2/3} e^u du$$

Now with the *incomplete gamma function*

$$\gamma(s,z) = \int_{0}^{z} t^{s-1} e^{-t} dt$$

we can write $I_1$ as

$$I_1 = -\frac{1}{3} \frac{(-u)^{2/3}}{u^{2/3}}\gamma(1/3, -u)$$

and substituting back $u=ix^3$

$$I_1 = \frac{(-ix^3)^{2/3}}{3x^2} \gamma(1/3, -ix^3)$$

Similarly for the second integral

$$I_2 = \int i e^{-ix^3}dx$$

we have

$$I_2 = - \frac{(ix^3)^{2/3}}{3x^2} \gamma(1/3, ix^3)$$

Finally

$$\int sin(x^3)dx = \frac{(-ix^3)^{2/3} \gamma(1/3, -ix^3) + (ix^3)^{2/3} \gamma(1/3, ix^3)}{6x^2}+c$$

Answer (score 0):

How to integrate:

$$\int \sin (x^3)dx$$

Start with a series representation for:

$$f(x) = sin(x)$$

The **taylor's series** representation of sin(x):

$$
f(x) = sin(x) = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} x^{2n+1} 
$$

Substitute $x \rightarrow x^3$
$$
f(x^3) = sin(x^3) = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} (x^3)^{2n+1} 
$$

Integrate:

$$
I = \int f(x^3) dx = \int sin(x^3) dx = \int \bigg( \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} (x^3)^{2n+1} \bigg) dx
$$

$$
I=  \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \Bigg(\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} \bigg( \int (x^3)^{2n+1} dx \bigg)\Bigg)
$$

$$
I =  \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \Bigg(\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} \bigg( \int (x^3)^{2n+1} dx \bigg)\Bigg)
$$

$$
I =  \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \Bigg(\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} \bigg( \int x^{6n+3} dx \bigg)\Bigg)
$$

$$I = \sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^{6n+4}}{(2n+1)!(6n+4)} + C$$