# How to find indefinite integral of $\sin(x^3)$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I obtained$$\int\sin(x^3)dx=\frac{\cos(x^3)}{3x^2}$$ was my answer which is wrong.

Is this somehow related to the indefinite integral of $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$ being $\ln(f(x))$?

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange! Here's a mathjax tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: this function has not an elementary antiderivative

Comment: here you can find a WA Output: $$-\frac{1}{2} i \left(\frac{x \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{3},i x^3\right)}{3 \sqrt[3]{i
   x^3}}-\frac{x \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{3},-i x^3\right)}{3 \sqrt[3]{-i x^3}}\right)$$

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral#Generalization).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integral of $\sin (x^3)dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1328151/integral-of-sin-x3dx) or [Integral $\int\sin(x^3)dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2307358/integral-int-sinx3-rm-dx?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Probably, one of the simplest things you could do  is to expand the integrand as an infinite series using
$$\sin(y)= \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} y^{2n+1}$$ making $$\sin(x^3)= \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} x^{6n+3}$$ $$\int \sin(x^3)\,dx=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(6n+4)(2n+1)!} x^{6n+4}$$ Otherwise, you will face quite complex functions.

Comment: "The only thing..." Nah, you could also use $\sin(y)=\Im(e^{iy})$ and apply incomplete Gamma functions for example.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt. For sure, you are right ! I shall edit. Cheers.

Comment: On the other hand, I'd say this is the most realistic approach.